# Class method paremeter not working as intended when organized into variables

Tags: python, class, oop, methods, pygame

Hi am relatively new to programming in general so I could be asking a pretty dum dum question but there's this problem about parameters just confused me and it seems like they're the same code but the result is different
Main Code

main.py

```
import pygame, settings, obstacles, npc, player
from utils import *
pygame.init()

window = pygame.display.set_mode((settings.WIDTH, settings.HEIGHT))
FPS = pygame.time.Clock()

player = player.Player(window)
box = obstacles.Box(window)

# Loop

run = True

while run:
    FPS.tick(settings.FPS)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    player.player_control()

    window.fill((settings.BLACK))
    player.render()
    player.jump_cooldown_bar(settings.JUMP_BAR_X, settings.JUMPCOOLDOWN_BAR, settings.JUMP_BAR_WIDTH, settings.JUMP_BAR_HEIGHT)
    box.render(settings.OFFSET_X, settings.OFFSET_Y) # not changing on class
    pygame.display.update()

print(player.color)
```

player.py

```
import pygame, settings
pygame.init()

class Player():
    def __init__(self, window) -> None:
         self.window = window
         self.color = settings.OLIVE
         self.player_x = settings.PLAYER_X
         self.player_y = settings.PLAYER_Y
         self.player_w = settings.PLAYER_WIDTH
         self.player_h = settings.PLAYER_HEIGHT

         self.jump = False
         self.jump_count = settings.JUMP_LIMIT
         self.jump_timer = settings.JUMP_COOLDOWN
         self.jump_itiration = settings.JUMP_ITIRATION
         self.jump_itiration_limit = settings.JUMP_ITIRATION_LIMIT

         self.render()
         
    
    def render(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(self.window, self.color, (self.player_x, self.player_y, self.player_w, self.player_h)) 
        
    def player_control(self):
        self.player_movement()
        self.player_jump()

    def player_movement(self):
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        if keys[pygame.K_a]:
            self.player_x -= settings.VELOCITY
            settings.JUMP_BAR_X -= settings.VELOCITY
            settings.OFFSET_X -= settings.VELOCITY
        if keys[pygame.K_d]:
            self.player_x += settings.VELOCITY
            settings.JUMP_BAR_X += settings.VELOCITY
            settings.OFFSET_X += settings.VELOCITY
        if keys[pygame.K_w] and self.jump_count >= 0:
            self.jump = True
            self.jump_count -= 1
            self.jump_timer = settings.JUMP_COOLDOWN

    def player_jump(self):
        if self.player_y < settings.GROUND and not self.jump:
            self.player_y += settings.GRAVITY
            settings.JUMPCOOLDOWN_BAR += settings.GRAVITY
            settings.OFFSET_Y += settings.GRAVITY

        if self.jump_itiration < self.jump_itiration_limit and self.jump:
            self.player_y -= settings.GRAVITY
            settings.JUMPCOOLDOWN_BAR -= settings.GRAVITY
            settings.OFFSET_Y -= settings.GRAVITY
            self.jump_itiration += 1
            if self.jump_itiration == self.jump_itiration_limit:
                self.jump = False
                self.jump_itiration = 0

        if not self.jump and self.jump_count <= 0:
            self.jump_timer -= 1
            if self.jump_timer == 0:
                self.jump_count = settings.JUMP_LIMIT
    
    def jump_cooldown_bar(self, x, y, w, h):
        w -= self.jump_timer
        print(f"changed {w}")
        pygame.draw.rect(self.window, (settings.RED), (x, y, w, h), 0, 1)
```

settings.py

```
WIDTH = 1440
HEIGHT = 720
FPS = 60
VELOCITY = 15
GROUND = 576
GRAVITY = 17

PLAYER_X = 0
PLAYER_Y = 576
JUMP_COOLDOWN = 50
JUMP_LIMIT = 10
JUMP_ITIRATION = 0
JUMP_ITIRATION_LIMIT = 15

JUMP_BAR_X = 6
JUMP_BAR_Y = 9
JUMP_BAR_WIDTH = 130
JUMP_BAR_HEIGHT = 7
JUMPCOOLDOWN_BAR = PLAYER_Y - JUMP_BAR_Y

BOX_X = 500
BOX_Y = 400

OFFSET_X = 0
OFFSET_Y = 0

CALC_SIZE = WIDTH // 10 
PLAYER_WIDTH = CALC_SIZE
PLAYER_HEIGHT = CALC_SIZE


BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
OLIVE = (136, 196, 23)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
```

Problem:
When this method is used the program works properly

```
def jump_cooldown_bar(self, x, y, w, h):
        w -= self.jump_timer
        print(f"changed {w}")
        pygame.draw.rect(self.window, (settings.RED), (x, y, w, h), 0, 1)
```

Yet changing it into this messed it up

```
def jump_cooldown_bar(self):
        settings.JUMP_BAR_WIDTH -= self.jump_timer
        pygame.draw.rect(self.window, (settings.RED), (settings.JUMP_BAR_X, settings.JUMPCOOLDOWN_BAR, settings.JUMP_BAR_WIDTH, settings.JUMP_BAR_HEIGHT), 0, 1)
```

What went wrong? the bar is suppose to change as the player jumps twice the bar should be depleted and when full allows the player to jump again.

Comment: Python has not concept of in-out parameters. `w -= self.jump_timer` changes `w`, however it does not change the argument `settings.JUMP_BAR_WIDTH`. If you change `w` then `settings.JUMP_BAR_WIDTH` will not magically change. `w` is a copy of `settings.JUMP_BAR_WIDTH`. Parameters are passed by value.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Rabbid76 comment

Fixed Code

```
def jump_cooldown_bar(self):
        jumpbar_w = settings.JUMP_BAR_WIDTH
        jumpbar_w -= self.jump_timer
        jumpbar_h = settings.JUMP_BAR_HEIGHT

        jumpbar_x = settings.JUMP_BAR_X
        jumpbar_y = settings.JUMPCOOLDOWN_BAR


        pygame.draw.rect(self.window, (settings.RED), (jumpbar_x, jumpbar_y, jumpbar_w, jumpbar_h), 0, 1)
```